# How to create product catalogue in pdf

Tags: pdf, latex, pdf-generation

In this case I have XML data source and external images files whole together representing products catalogue. The basic structure of XML document is following:

- categories
- subcategories
- products

I'm looking for a tool to convert described data source to pdf document, preferably with basic navigation functionality and hierarchical structure. Probably I can do it writing XSLT stylesheet, or writing code in some script language for generating TEX document. Can anyone  provide any good LaTeX style for product catalogue or open source tool for generating pdf catalogues?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you the famous [iText Java](http://itextpdf.com/) pdf library generation.

You can load data from XML and generate any type of PDF.
You have to write Java classes to create these type of documents.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use XSL-FO if I thought a transformation would work or iText if I was writing a Java app and expressing it in code worked better.